# Quicksort floats

Tags: c, floating-point, quicksort

I need to read a file (and store the information in arrays) containing the student number, name and first name and grade of different students, then display the all this information and then use quicksort to display the this information now sorted from highest to lowest grades. The output displays only the information before the quicksort. Anyone knows why my quicksort is wrong? Disclaimer : some words in my code are in french.

Here is a sample of the file :

> 1000 Docteur             Albert              65.5
>
> 1001 Solo                Hanz                23.4
>
> 1002 Caillou             Frederic            78.7
>
> 1003 Viky                Bryan               98.6
>
> 1004 Encas               Christian           67.7

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_PERS 200
#define MAX_LONG_NP 15

int numero[MAX_PERS];
char nom[MAX_PERS][MAX_LONG_NP]; 
char prenom[MAX_PERS][MAX_LONG_NP];
float note[MAX_PERS];


void afficher(float note[], int nbPers, char *quand)   /* a effacer lorsque tout fonctionnera bien */
{
    int i;
    
    printf("Contenu du tableau %s le tri\n\n", quand);
    
    for(i=0;i<nbPers;i++)
        printf("%3.2f\n", note[i]);
}




void echanger (float *P1, float *P2)
{ 
    float tempo;

    tempo = *P1 ;
    *P1 = *P2;
    *P2 = tempo;
}
        
        
        
void  partitionner ( float note[], int debut, int fin, int *P )
{ 
    int G = debut , D = fin  ;

    float Val_Pivot = note[debut];

    while ( G <= D  &&  note[G] >= Val_Pivot) 
        G++;

    while (note[D] < Val_Pivot) 
        D--;

    if ( G < D ) 
        echanger(&note[G], &note[D]);

    while ( G <= D )
        echanger (&note[debut], &note[D]);
        
    *P = D ;
}



void quickSort ( float note[], int gauche, int droite )
{ 
    int indPivot ;

    if (gauche < droite)
        {
            partitionner ( note, gauche, droite, &indPivot);
            quickSort ( note, gauche, indPivot - 1 );
            quickSort ( note, indPivot + 1, droite);
        }
}



int main()
{
        FILE *aLire = fopen("notes.txt", "r");
    
    int nbPers=0;
    
    while(!feof(aLire))
    {
        fscanf(aLire, "%d%s%s%f\n", &numero[nbPers], &nom[nbPers], &prenom[nbPers], &note[nbPers]);
        nbPers++;  
    }   
    fclose(aLire);  
    
    afficher(note, nbPers, "avant");  
    
    quickSort(note, 0, nbPers-1);
    
    afficher(note, nbPers, "apres");
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Review [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359)

Comment: Please note you haven’t asked a question. What is the problem here?

Comment: Post lacks a question.  Quelle est ta question?

Comment: Code will fail if any name is more than 14 characters, more than 200 names,  Check return value of `fscanf()` and see it is is always 4, use width limits, check range, enable all compiler wanings:  Re-write loop: `while(nbPers <         MAX_PERS && fscanf(aLire, "%d%14s%14s%f", &numero[nbPers], nom[nbPers], prenom[nbPers], &note[nbPers]) == 4) {  nbPers++;   }`

Comment: Yes, a question would be nice, sorry. I’ve edited my “question” to have an actual question. Thanks

Comment: I have tested my program on integers (the student numbers) and it worked but for some reason when I try with floats (the grades) it doesn’t work.

Comment: Does it fail with just the 5 lines of sample data?

Comment: Yes, it does fail.

Comment: Sure about `while ( G <= D )
        echanger (&note[debut], &note[D]);`?  .  It certainly _looks_ like a   infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! Turns out I was missing { before the first while and } before the third one.

Comment: You can even post your own solution/answer.